# Is there an abbreviation for palisade cells?

Tags: cell-biology

I want to know if there are any abbreviation for **palisade cells** and **spongy cells**?
Just like there is an abbrevation for **macrophages** (**MP**).

Comment: The more common abbreviation for macrophage is actually MΦ, using the Greek letter phi.

Comment: MP isn't really an abbreviation specific for macrophages. In a paper about leucocytes, authors might use MP, but usually only after initially defining that (e.g. ...yada yada macrophage (MP) activity...). So, no. Commonly discussed things have abbreviations (EEG, EKG, EMG, CBC, HR, RR, VT, ASHD, etc.) and very specific things (e.g. CYP51A1) that are too long to repeatedly write out. MP can be "middle phalynx" and a number of other things.